# How to add ROOM queries that take parameters and return data

Tags: java, repository, android-room, viewmodel

I am trying to create a new room database query that takes a parameter and returns a list. All the documents I read and videos I watch only show me as far as the DAO query (which I have done) but what I cannot find is how to create the subsequent queries for repository and viewModel classes.
This is my DAO query;

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE name = :reselectedPlayerName")
List<Member> getPlayersForReselection(String reselectedPlayerName);
```

I have successfully created a 'LiveData' query (for another task) which does not take any parameters, but I do NOT want a Livedata query this time and I cannot see how to create the query in the repository class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as always is generally simple!... but when you cannot see the wood for the trees....
If anybody wants more detail, I am happy to detail what I found and what I did but this is what I ended up doing;
(I know I said I didn't want to use LiveData but I did just for proving)

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE name = :aStr")
LiveData<List<Member>> getPlayersForReselectionDb(String aStr);
```

REPOSITORY

```
public LiveData<List<Member>> getPlayersForReselectionDb(String aStr){
    reselectedMembers = memberDAO.getPlayersForReselectionDb(aStr);
    return reselectedMembers;
}
```

VIEWMODEL

```
public LiveData<List<Member>> getPlayersForReselectionDb(String aStr) {
    reselectedMembers = memberRepository.getPlayersForReselectionDb(aStr);
    return reselectedMembers;
}
```

FRAGMENT

```
MemberViewModel memberViewModel = new 
ViewModelProvider(this).get(MemberViewModel.class);

memberViewModel.getPlayersForReselectionDb("Fred Bloggs").observe(this, 
new Observer<List<Member>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<Member> members) {`enter code here`}
    }
});
```